Converting a gravitation potential from spherical to Cartesian and adding arbitrary tilt
I am working on utilising different potentials in my N-body code to do toy simulations (massless particles in a potential. However, I ran into issues converting a certain potential from a paper into Cartesian coordinates and making the potential act as if it is tilted.
The potential in question is a rough estimation of a toroidal potential in spherical polar coordinates:
$\Phi(r,\theta)=-\frac{GM}{R_t}\left[1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{r}{R_t}\right)^2P_2(\cos\theta)+\frac{3}{8}\left(\frac{r}{R_t}\right)^4P_4(\cos\theta)\right]$,
Where $P_2$ and $P_4$ are the $2^{\rm{nd}}$ and $4^{\rm{th}}$ order Legendre polynomials, $R_t$ is a scale value of the torus, and $r/\theta$ are the spherical polar coordinates.
For my N-body code I want to add a "tilt" as if the potential is not in the $(x,y)$ plane but tilted by an arbitrary angle $\theta_a$ around the $x$-axis. However, the integrator in my code (Leapfrog integrator) is set to work with Cartesian coordinates. If it were in spherical coordinates then the solution would be just $\Phi(r,\theta+\theta_a)$, correct? I have been unsuccessful in converting my integrator to spherical, so my question and goal is properly converting this potential to Cartesian and adding that tilt. This potential is later differentiated to get the forces/accelerations and integrate a particle's path.
My current methodology is performing a straightforward conversions from spherical to Cartesian and then substituting $y$ for $y\cos(\theta_a)-z\sin(\theta_a)$ and $z$ for $y\sin(\theta_a)+z\cos(\theta_a)$. This has made the simulations work, but for some reason the results are not matching theoretical predictions of some values for this toroidal potential.
My main question is if my current methodology is correct, and if not, what a proper conversion + tilt would look like? I've been attempting different things with no success. Ideally, just using a Leapfrog integrator in spherical coordinates would seem easier, but rewriting the code appears more difficult for me at the moment. I would like to know the proper method of converting this potential.

What is a tilt? Normally a tilt is a linear ramp in some direction, which is also a background uniform field, e.g $V' = -\alpha z = -(\alpha r\cos\theta)$ so $\vec F' = \alpha$, but you have $\theta \rightarrow \theta + \theta_a$, which looks like a rotation, but not really, since it's the polar angle.

@JEB I am not aware of that definition of tilt, I am referencing the astronomical definition as the original problem is not a potential - it's a torus made up of particles. The symmetry axis of the torus is tilted with respect to the initial spin axis of a galactic disc. The potential represents this torus in the (x,y) plane and the disc is modelled as a tilted disc - how would I modify the potential to act as if it's rotated while the disc remains in the (x,y) plane instead?
